# Make a text file my automatically updated background?

Tags: scripts, desktop-background, notes

I want to make a "to-do" list my wallpaper. I was hoping to be able to write a text file, save it, and have the background be updated each time I edit file. Is this possible?

Comment: To my knowledge,this is not an existing functionality, but it may be something that can be scripted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The script below watches a textfile that you can edit. If the file is changed, it will create a new layer over your wallpaper with the text of the file.

#### Options

you can define:

- text size
- text color
- number of columns
- (max) number of lines per column
- border width (around the text blocks)

#### How to use

The script uses Imagemagick, you might have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then:

- Copy the script below into an empty file and save it as `walltext.py`.
- Edit, if you want specific settings, the options in the head section of the script.
- *Into the same folder*, copy the wallpaper of your choice , name it (exactly) `original.jpg`
  N.B.- It is important that the proportions of your wallpaper match the proportions of your screen's resolution, else the text will not be positioned properly.
- *In the same folder*, create an empty textfile named (exactly) notes.txt. This is the file to make your todolist or whatever you'd like to have on your screen.

Run the script by the command:

```
python3 /path/to/walltext.py
```

Now start editing your text file. Every five seconds, the wallpaper is updated if needed (after you saved the changes):

#### Examples

*1 column, max 30 lines per column*

[image]

*2 columns, max 20 lines per column*

[image]

*3 columns, max 10 lines per column*

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os
import time

curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
curr_wall = curr_dir+"/"+"original.jpg"
notes = curr_dir+"/"+"notes.txt"

#--
text_color = "white"   # text color
size = "20"            # text size (real size depends on the scale factor of your wallpaper)
border = 120           # space around your text blocks
columns = 2            # (max) number of columns
n_lines = 10           # (max) number of lines per column
#--

def run_command(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

def get_value(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").strip()

def read_text(file):
    with open(file) as src:
        return [l.strip() for l in src.readlines()]

def slice_lines(lines, n_lines, columns):
    markers = [i for i in range(len(lines)) if i % n_lines == 0]
    last = len(lines); markers = markers+[last] if markers[-1] != last else markers
    textblocks = [lines[markers[i]:markers[i+1]] for i in range(len(markers)-1)]
    filled_blocks = len(textblocks)
    if filled_blocks < columns:
        for n in range(columns - filled_blocks):
            textblocks.insert(len(textblocks), [])
    for i in range(columns):
        textblocks[i] = ("\n").join(textblocks[i])
    return textblocks[:columns]

def create_section(psize, text, layer):
    run_command("convert -background none -fill "+text_color+" -border "+str(border)+\
                  " -bordercolor none -pointsize "+size+" -size "+psize+\
                  " caption:"+'"'+text+'" '+layer)

def combine_sections(layers):
    run_command("convert "+image_1+" "+image_2+" "+"+append "+span_image)
    pass

def set_overlay():
    boxes = slice_lines(read_text(notes), n_lines, columns)
    resolution = get_value('identify -format "%wx%h" '+curr_wall).split("x")
    w = str(int(int(resolution[0])/columns)-2*border)
    h = str(int(resolution[1])-2*border)
    layers = []
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        layer = curr_dir+"/"+"layer_"+str(i+1)+".png"
        create_section(w+"x"+h, boxes[i], layer)
        layers.append(layer)
    run_command("convert "+(" ").join(layers)+" "+"+append "+curr_dir+"/"+"layer_span.png")
    wall_img = curr_dir+"/"+"walltext.jpg"
    run_command("convert "+curr_wall+" "+curr_dir+"/"+"layer_span.png"+" -background None -layers merge "+wall_img)
    run_command("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///"+wall_img)
    for img in [img for img in os.listdir(curr_dir) if img.startswith("layer_")]:
        os.remove(curr_dir+"/"+img)

while True:
    text_1 = read_text(notes)
    time.sleep(5)
    text_2 = read_text(notes)
    if text_2 != text_1:
        set_overlay()
```

#### Notes

- More options can be added to the script, more info on Imagemagick's options can be found [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/).

Comment: This is perfect for what I need, except one thing: Can I make it so that it does this _over_ my current background? i.e. instead of bg_color = "white" somehow make it overlay? I'll mark as solved either way. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks again! It seems to work pretty well, however, if I add an apostrophe (but not a quotation mark) it doesn't seem to recognise that sentence, and will refuse to write it. Like this: http://i.imgur.com/NqoU2X3.gif

Comment: also, is there a way to change alignment/ make two columns? Lot's of questions, but this is fantastic!

Comment: I hadn't yet, but I did, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam the ' is easy to fix, I will update my answer later this morning.

Comment: thanks! it also seems to not work on startup (i.e. adding python3 /desitnationfile to startup applications). Thanks again for being so helpful!

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam does the path to your file contain spaces?

Comment: no, it's /home/joop/Documents/ubuntu/walltext.py

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam and your command = `python3 /home/joop/Documents/ubuntu/walltext.py`?

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam fixed the quote issue, will add the overlay and column (free to set any number of columns) function after the weekend. About the startup applications: It must be a typo, is your command `python3 /home/joop/Documents/ubuntu/walltext.py` (Don't forget the `python3` unless you made it executable)? Isn't the file located in a subfolder?

Comment: I had the command right, but I got it to work through making it executable, and setting the file itself as what's being opened by the startup applications!

Comment: @GuyfromAmsterdam updated my answer.

Comment: It's perfect. Thank you so much. I had some issues with resizing the image but once that worked out the text was perfectly sized too. Thanks again!

Comment: this is great, @JacobVlijm can you make this script available on github with a license , please ?

Comment: @ALJIMohamed thanks a lot! I think I will :) I might smoothen it a bit to make it easyer to use. Thatnks for the suggestion!

Comment: please keep me updated by the link to the repo ... :) have a nice day

Comment: @ALJIMohamed I will, have a nice day too!

Answer (score -1):

I've modified the code above to put random quotes on the wallpaper every hour. Enjoy :)
http://forraskod.blogspot.hu/2016/01/linux-hatterkep-veletlenszeru.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os
import time
import random

curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
curr_wall = curr_dir+"/"+"original.jpg"
notes = curr_dir+"/"+"notes.txt"

#--
text_color = "white"   # text color
size = "80"            # text size (real size depends on the scale factor of your wallpaper)
border = 480           # space around your text blocks
columns = 1            # (max) number of columns
n_lines = 3          # (max) number of lines per column
#--

def run_command(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

def get_value(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8").strip()

def read_text(file):
    with open(file) as src:
        return [l.strip() for l in src.readlines()]

def slice_lines(lines, n_lines, columns):
    markers = [i for i in range(len(lines)) if i % n_lines == 0]
    last = len(lines); markers = markers+[last] if markers[-1] != last else markers
    textblocks = [lines[markers[i]:markers[i+1]] for i in range(len(markers)-1)]
    filled_blocks = len(textblocks)
    if filled_blocks < columns:
        for n in range(columns - filled_blocks):
            textblocks.insert(len(textblocks), [])
    for i in range(columns):
        textblocks[i] = ("\n").join(textblocks[i])
    return textblocks[:columns]

def create_section(psize, text, layer):
    run_command("convert -background none -fill "+text_color+" -border "+str(border)+\
                  " -bordercolor none -pointsize "+size+" -size "+psize+\
                  " caption:"+'"'+text+'" '+layer)

def combine_sections(layers):
    run_command("convert "+image_1+" "+image_2+" "+"+append "+span_image)
    pass

def set_overlay(): # Read the file "notes" as specified above, display text in columns
    boxes = slice_lines(read_text(notes), n_lines, columns)
    resolution = get_value('identify -format "%wx%h" '+curr_wall).split("x")
    w = str(int(int(resolution[0])/columns)-2*border)
    h = str(int(resolution[1])-2*border)
    layers = []
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        layer = curr_dir+"/"+"layer_"+str(i+1)+".png"
        create_section(w+"x"+h, boxes[i], layer)
        layers.append(layer)
    run_command("convert "+(" ").join(layers)+" "+"+append "+curr_dir+"/"+"layer_span.png")
    wall_img = curr_dir+"/"+"walltext.jpg"
    run_command("convert "+curr_wall+" "+curr_dir+"/"+"layer_span.png"+" -background None -layers merge "+wall_img)
    run_command("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///"+wall_img)
    for img in [img for img in os.listdir(curr_dir) if img.startswith("layer_")]:
        os.remove(curr_dir+"/"+img)

def set_single_overlay(): # DEFAULT, read 1 line from "notes" file as specified above
    resolution = get_value('identify -format "%wx%h" '+curr_wall).split("x")
    w = str(int(int(resolution[0])/columns)-2*border)
    h = str(int(resolution[1])-2*border)
    layers = []

    layer = curr_dir+"/"+"layer_1.png"
    #print(w)
    #print(h)
    create_section(w+"x"+h, text_1, layer)
    layers.append(layer)

    run_command("convert "+(" ").join(layers)+" "+"+append "+curr_dir+"/"+"layer_span.png")
    wall_img = curr_dir+"/"+"walltext.jpg"
    run_command("convert "+curr_wall+" "+curr_dir+"/"+"layer_span.png"+" -background None -layers merge "+wall_img)
    run_command("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///"+wall_img)
    for img in [img for img in os.listdir(curr_dir) if img.startswith("layer_")]:
        os.remove(curr_dir+"/"+img)

print("Walltext started.")
print (curr_wall)
print (notes)

while True:
    text_1 = random.choice(open(notes).readlines())
    print(text_1)
    set_single_overlay()
    time.sleep(3600)

#    text_2 = read_text(notes)
#    if text_2 != text_1:
#        set_overlay()
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/517263)

Comment: Good point, I'll update it.