# Can I change the contents of the Keyboard Shortcut List that shows up when I hold down super?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

It occurred to me that this could be a very convenient way to keep a little bit of information sitting just in the background, ready whenever I need it.

I am referring to this list

[image: Keyboard shortcut overlay in Unity]

Comment: If it is for information on the desktop, http://askubuntu.com/questions/556723/make-a-text-file-my-automatically-updated-background/556769#556769 might be of use.

Comment: I filed a feature suggestion on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1591109). You can add yourself to it, to make it heard.

Answer (score 1):

The model of the keyboard-shortcuts overlay is hard coded in unity, so no customization is available for the time being.